# xadmin django reload no defined

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I use python 3.5 django 1.11 and trying xadmin 0.5

I install successfully by pip xadmin.

1. set up appinstalled with     `xadmin`, `crispy_forms`, `reversion`
2. set up urls       `url(r'^xadmin/', include(xadmin.site.urls))`
3. trying `python manage.py syncdb`
4. error message: reload not defined
5. make change to import from importlib import reload and delete
               # sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
6. now error message: app doesnt load ...

anyone can help me to setting xadmin thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From django 1.9 `syncdb` command is removed. Use instead

```
python manage.py makemigrations app-name
```

and then

```
python manage.py migrate
```